# Need Assistance in creating a password/username system with batch

Tags: batch-file

Okay so heres what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to make a batch file with a user input for a login.  I would like to have the ability to create a new account.  I have an idea, I just don't know how to go around implementing  it.  I have the user input his desired username and password and have it save to a text document like so:

```
@echo off
set /p user=Enter your desired username:
set /p pass=Enter your desired password:
echo %user% >> log.txt
echo %pass% >> log.txt
```

That works fine for me, but now what I would like to do is call up those two lines so that when they entered the correct username and password it will take them to their menu.
I know for a fact the the call won't work well with this. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

P.S. I am aware that the txt file is not secure. I have ways around that.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this to recover the saved values:

```
(
set /P savedUser=
set /P savedPass=
) < log.txt
```

This way:

```
if "%user%" == "%savedUser%" if "%pass%" == "%savedPass%" goto accessGranted
```

Another way to save the values is this:

```
echo set savedUser=%user%> log.bat
echo set savedPass=%pass%>> log.bat
```

and to recover the saved values:

```
call log
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm decently proud of this :) This is pretty much a complete overhaul of your method.
This has two different files: login.bat which handles the login and login2.bat which handles the registration.
login.bat:

```
@echo off
choice /c:RL /m "Choose an option: Register (R) or Login (L).:
if errorlevel 2 goto login
if errorlevel 1 goto register
:register
start /wait C:\[path]\login2.bat
cls
goto login
:in
cls
echo Welcome %u%
echo.
echo Bla Bla Bla or start "a program"
pause
exit
:login
set /p u=Username
set /p p=Password
```

and login2.bat:

```
@echo off
:a
set /p a="Choose a Username"
set /p b="Choose a Password"
echo.
choice /m "Are you sure you would like your Username to be %a% and your Password to be %b%?"
if errorlevel 2 goto a
set q="if %%u%% equ %a% if %%p%% equ %b% goto in"
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in (%q%) do set m=%%I
echo %m% >>C:\[path]\login.bat
exit
```

The reason why :in, the label which handles what happens after you login successfully has to be in the middle instead of at the end of login.bat is so that the username/password combinations could be appended to the :login label. Obviously you could add other embellishments and change the name of the files, but this is my basic design.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do

```
@echo off
:: some code here
set /p username=please create a username:
set /p password=please create a password:
echo %username%>username.txt
echo %password%>password.txt
```

This will create a text file for both your username and password

I hope this helped. :)